# How to write a Spark Dataframe to Azure Event hub?

Tags: apache-spark, azure-eventhub, azure-synapse

I need to write a DataFrame in a Synapse Apache Spark Scala script to Azure Event Hub.

My solution is based on this article.
https://github.com/Azure/azure-event-hubs-spark/blob/master/docs/structured-streaming-eventhubs-integration.md#writing-data-to-eventhubs

How would I convert a Dataframe with multiple columns to a DataFrame with a single column called 'body' with all the columns as json?

I am using Scala and Spark 3

Here is a solution I found where toJson creates a column called 'value'.

```
df.toJSON.selectExpr("value as body")
```

Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write custom dataframe to eventhub from ADLS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70375424/how-to-write-custom-dataframe-to-eventhub-from-adls)

Comment: I could not get that solution to work in Scala. Maybe those functions are only available in python library.
My solution below works but I would like to avoid the extra Dataframe that is created between toJSON and selectExpr

Answer (score 1):

I have been doing `df.select(struct(*[c for c in df.columns]).alias("body"))` and it has been working well for me. It will take your dataframe as it is and make the whole thing the value of a new dataframe where the column name is "body".

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution.

First, get the connection string from the eventhub. The correct connection string will have 'EntityPath' with eventhub name. It is not the connection string at the event hub namespace.

eg.

```
val connectionString="Endpoint=sb://{youreventhub}.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName={policyname};SharedAccessKey={yourkey};EntityPath={eventhub}";
```

Create an event hub configuration.

```
import org.apache.spark.eventhubs._
val ehWriteConf = EventHubsConf(connectionString);
```

Convert your dataframe to a dataframe with column body and write to eventhub.

```
df.toJSON.selectExpr("value as body").
write.format("eventhubs").options(ehWriteConf.toMap).
save()
```